# Best practice for manual role switching (for testing) with Windows authentication in .NET

Tags: .net, authentication, active-directory

We are migrating an old .NET Framework application to .NET 7. Lots of stuff gets more modern but we will have to keep the underlying Windows authentication.

Users get tailored access to the application based on the AD groups they are in.

Windows authentication per se works out of the box in .NET 7.
`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`

Now we are looking for a way to allow testing the application with specific roles.
On our testing stage, we want to display a role selector that can override the roles given by the AD groups.

In the legacy application this was done using a library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.EmbeddedSts/1.0.2

But this is not available in .NET 7.

Is there a common / recommended way to solve such a scenario?

EDIT: it is all about a web application. Therefore, we need a way for the user to choose its testing role. This musst then be communicated to the backend for evaluation.

Comment: Have you looked into role-based and policy-based authorization?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0